# How to use gtk from motif

Tags: linux, gtk, motif

I have an motif based application that runs on Linux. Lately I have been trying to create and launch gtk dialogs from with in the motif application.

However I notice that the two tool kits are incompatible. If I move the gtk dialog over the motif based application, it greys/blurs out the motif parent window.

Could some one please tell me how I could possibly fix this problem, and would be great if some one could post tips on how people should create gtk based widgets/dialogs from within motif applications and probably over a period of time migrate completely to using gtk?

Comment: I really won't try to do that. Mixing two toolkits (with two event loops) is usually a nightmare, and *Motif* is really dead. Consider recoding your old rusty Motif application, or leave it alone (or use another process to run Gtk).

Answer (score 1):

Motif is an obsolete widget toolkit. Plus, as Basile Starynkevitch commented above, mixing toolkits is a bad idea. There is no way to fix the compatibility problem because they are not compatible widget toolkits.